Exception: Cannot retrieve next object: the iterator has reached the end
I'm trying to iterate in diferents rows to collect data from users that have answered a Google forms and generate diferent documents with their data. So far I've acomplished that part of my code, but there's a problem when I try to classifie their documents in several folders. It's like a hierarchy that starts classifing form their course (highschool), and then from their class (A, B...), but i only get this exception.
Exception: Cannot retrieve next object: the iterator has reached the end.
And I don't know what to do to solve it
var course = dataBase.getRange("L" + row).getValue();
var class = dataBase.getRange("M" + row).getValue();

var masterFolder = locBase.getFoldersByName("individual_documents");

var locBase = DriveApp.getFileById("DOCUMENT_ID").getParents().next();

if (!masterFolder.hasNext()) {

            // If there isn't a principal folder, it creates it
            masterFolder= locBase.createFolder("individual_documents");

            // Creation of the first sub-folder (the course one)
            var courseFolder = masterFolder.next().createFolder(course);

            // The document is moved to the subfolder
            document.moveTo(courseFolder);

          } else {

            // If the principal folder its created it searches de course folder
            var courseFolder = masterFolder.next().getFoldersByName(course);

            if (!courseFolder.hasNext()) {

              // If the course folder doesn't exist, it creates it
              courseFolder = masterFolder.next().createFolder(course);

              // The sub-subfolder it's created (the class one) inside of the course folder
              var classFolder = courseFolder .createFolder(class);

              // The document is moved to the sub-subfolder
              document.moveTo(classFolder);

            } else {

              // If the subfolder exists, it searches the sub-subfolder inside of it
              var classFolder = courseFolder.next().getFoldersByName(class);

              if (!classFolder .hasNext()) {

                // If the sub-subfolder doesn't exist, it creates it
                var classFolder = courseFolder .next().createFolder(class);

                // The document is moved to the sub-subfolder
                document.moveTo(classFolder);


I expected to get in my Drive the main folder with the subfolders that contain de documents of each user, but it does not even manage to generate the documents that I need

The code is not complete, i.e, masterFolder is not defined. Please add a [mcve].

Where is the error Exception: Cannot retrieve next object: the iterator has reached the end. in your showing script? By the way, when you save your script, doesn't an error occur at createFolder(class) or the line where a value is declared to class?

Sorry, I forgot about defining the classes "class" and "course" in the code that I had attached. And answering your questions, I don't get any type of error at createFolder(class) o where the class value is declared (because I have my code in other language, I changed the variables names to get help of anybody that could). And when I execute my code, from a function onOpen I get this error, I mean, before creating this code I didn't got the error, but now I get it.

class should not be used as a variable name in Google Apps Apps Script / JavaScript because it's used to declare Classes (Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

I used AI to help with me with this problem, and it created an iterator for each type of folder (masterFolder, courseFolder and classFolder) to check if it's created, it is really helpful, and now I don't get any type of error, and I'm getting the result that I expected I let the code attached if anyone is interested:

      var course = dataBase.getRange("L" + row).getValue();


      var class= dataBase.getRange("M" + row).getValue();

      var masterFolderIterator = locBase.getFoldersByName("individual_documents");

      var masterFolder;
      if (!masterFolderIterator.hasNext()) {
        masterFolder = locBase.createFolder("individual_documents");
      } else {
        masterFolder = masterFolderIterator.next();
      }

      var courseFolderIterator = masterFolder.getFoldersByName(course);
      var courseFolder;

      if (!courseFolderIterator.hasNext()) {
        courseFolder = masterFolder.createFolder(course);
      } else {
        courseFolder = courseFolderIterator.next();
      }

      var classFolderIterator = courseFolder.getFoldersByName(class);
      var classFolder;

      if (!classFolderIterator.hasNext()) {
        classFolder = courseFolder.createFolder(class);
      } else {
        classFolder = carpetaClaseIterator.next();
      }

      document.moveTo(carpetaClase);
    }

